# How to make static page permalink look pretty

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I have create new page with my custom template. This page will be used by users to ask questions. The defult permalink to my page is http:**//www.mysite.com/?page_id=26.**

This look ugly in address bar in the browser. I want it look pretty. For example just like in stackoverflow **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**

Please advice where to look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your posts permalink to anything other than the default one (from Settings -> Permalinks).

Create a page named Questions, and then create a page Ask with the Question page as its parent.